# Power BI - Many to Many relationships

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I'm trying to make a measure that needs two "many to many" relationships between the same tables to work.

Is this possible ? i'm trying to make it work but it seems that the PowerBi program doesn't permit this from happening.

It's a name column and a date column. i use filters based on this two columns but it only permits one relation. So, if i create a date relation the name filter doesn't work and vice versa.

Someone knows another way around it ?

The data is sensitive so i can't post it, but if needed i can try to make a fake one that shares its characteristics.

Comment: you can create a virtual relationship with TREATAS https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/propagate-filters-using-treatas-in-dax/

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to take a look.

Comment: This is the wrong way to go. Extract the name and the date column as dimension tables and create a star schema. [Understand star schema and the importance for Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/guidance/star-schema) Many:many relations will get you nowhere.

Comment: A mock up of the data would be helpful to answer this question.  It's difficult to understand why only one relationship is permitted - sounds like it might be a circular reference??